# Issue with intranet site

Tags: wordpress, intranet

We have a lamp word press intranet site running, however, the first time I load the site it doesn't load and says the page cannot be displayed. When I refresh the site it loads. Is this a problem with our server or dns or what?! We have no proxy and sometimes get this error message as well ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the best way forward is to first figure out which part of the process is failing, browser, computer or web server.

**Determine the most likely point of failure**

If the fault occurs on more than one computer, and with different browsers then it not likely to be browser or computer issue.  Therefore the next step is to look at the webserver.

**if it looks like a computer or browser issue**

If its only failing on one computer or browser the try flushing your browser cache, if that fails then it could be a network setup issue.  You could try setting you computers DNS network settings to point to your internet router and to your web servers IPs.

**if it seems like a web server issue**

1) Check settings of your network, try setting DNS to router and webserver. 
2)If you have a spare computer install fresh webserver and try using new test webserver to see if you get the same problems

and if all else fails get windows PC install WAMP;) or the ultimate solution switch it off and go the pub.